# Simultaneous read write on value object of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<ID,Object> map;
```

In my application, this map is high read and low write

Read works in following way:

```
public Response getObject() {
    Response response = createResponse();
    Object obj = map.get(ID);
    if (obj != null) {
        if (obj.getAttribute1() == some_value) {
            response.setAttr1(obj.getAttr1());
            response.setAttr2(obj.getAttr2());
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Update works in following way:

```
public void updateObject(Object obj, int action) {
    if (action == ADD) {
        map.put(obj.getID(), obj);
    } else if (action == UPDATE) {
        object oldObj = map.get(obj.getID());
        if (oldObj != null) {
            map.put(obj.getID(), obj);
        }
    } else if (action == REMOVE) {
        object oldObj = map.get(obj.getID());
        if (oldObj != null) {
            map.remove(obj.getID());
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is that,is ConcurrentHashMap is sufficient for above case to work in thread safe manner in multithreaded environment or I have to externally lock the Object by ReadWrite lock or use cloning of Object?

Suppose in a case when obj is read from map,ConcurrentHashMap will make sure it will return latest written object but what about when this object is removed/updated by writer thread just after read.Read object(which is already removed/updated from map) is used to prepare response object and its attribute are used to make certain decisions.

And what should be the better way to update map?

Answer (score 0):

For your code to be thread-safe with respect to the `ConcurrentHashMap`, you should be using the respective `compute` methods (which are performed atomically):

```
public Response getObject() {
    Response response = createResponse();

    map.computeIfPresent(ID, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == some_value) {
            response.setAttr1(v.getAttr1());
            response.setAttr2(v.getAttr2());
        }

        return v;
    }

    return response;
}
```

And:

```
public void updateObject(Object obj, int action) {
    if (action == ADD) {
        map.put(obj.getID(), obj);
    } else if (action == UPDATE) {
        map.computeIfPresent(obj.getID(), (k, v) -> obj);
    } else if (action == REMOVE) {
        map.remove(obj.getID());
    }
}
```

Comment: The read doesn't gain anything by using compute other than not needing to check if present.

Answer (score -1):

This is thread safe provided there is only one writer. Otherwise, there is a race condition between operation you perform. For this reason, there are operations which perform these actions atomically and simplify the code.

```
public void updateObject(Object obj, int action) {
    switch (action) {
        case ADD:
            map.put(obj.getID(), obj);
            break;

        case UPDATE:
            map.computeIfPresent(obj.getID(), (k, v) -> obj);
            break;

        case REMOVE:
            map.remove(obj.getID());
            break;
    }
}
```

Most likely, you don't need a special update operation and you could make it also `put`

I would highly recommend not using `Object` as a custom class but instead, use a new name.

> what about when this object is removed/updated by writer thread just after read

If the object is removed it has no impact on another thread holding that reference. If the object is updated by putting a new object in the map, this will be fine, however if you update the object added, this might not be thread safe.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because `Map#putIfPresent` doesn't exist.